# How to get current template file used by WordPress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, themes

Consider I've 3 template files

```
archive.php 
archive-books.php 
common.php <-- required_once by both archive.php & archive-books.php
```

So whether `archive-books.php` or `archive.php` is being loaded depends on the current post type.

Since they both include `common.php`, in the `common.php`, how to I know which current WordPress template is picked? i.e. `archive.php`  or `archive-books.php` ?

Comment: And when/where do you want to obtain that information, because this is important...?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you could simply follow the logic: determine [if you're on an archive page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) and [what the current post type is](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/). Like this:

```
if (is_archive() && 'books' == get_post_type) { do your thing }
```

Or you could use the [function specific for checking this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/):

```
if (is_post_type_archive('books')) { do your thing }
```

Comment: That tells them what archive or post type they're on, not which file is being used.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But the question is, if you're inside `common.php`, how do you know by which template it was called? You can know that by looking at the post&archive type, because that determines which template it was. Assuming, indeed, that the normal WP hierarchy is followed.

Answer (score -1):

try this to check if your specific post type archive file is present

```
$postType = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
if(file_exists('archive-'.$postType.'.php')){
    // You have the specific archive file for the post type
}else{
    // You don't have the specific archive file for the post type
}
```